# jQuery when output the promise object rather than result

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, pouchdb

I want to get the count of each database in the PouchDB. When I tried to wrap it in the jQuery promise, when it's complete it send the promise object instead of result to the then();

```
function validateAppData(event) {

        var db1 = new PouchDB( "distributors" );
        var db2 = new PouchDB( "categories" );
        var db3 = new PouchDB( "genericTypes" );
        var db4 = new PouchDB( "products" );

        $.when(
            db1.info(),
            db2.info(),
            db3.info(),
            db4.info()
        ).then( function( distributors, categories, genericTypes, products ) {
            console.log(distributors);
            console.log(categories);
            console.log(genericTypes);
            console.log(products);
            console.log("all done")
            console.log(distributors.doc_count);
        } );
    }
```

**The console output as follow.**

[image]

Please let me know how can I get the response in each object.

Thank you.

Comment: `Promise.all()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Using_Promise.all

Comment: does function `PouchDB#info` return a jQuery promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to handle multiple promises and once, check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Using_Promise.all).

```
var db1 = new PouchDB("distributors");
var db2 = new PouchDB("categories");
var db3 = new PouchDB("genericTypes");
var db4 = new PouchDB("products");

Promise.all([
  db1.info(),
  db2.info(),
  db3.info(),
  db4.info()
]).then(([ distributors, categories, genericTypes, products ]) => {
  console.log(distributors);
  console.log(categories);
  console.log(genericTypes);
  console.log(products);
  console.log("all done");
  console.log(distributors.doc_count);
});
```

Comment: you're missing some important `()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all()`. jQuery deferred objects do not necessarily handle `Promise` objects the same as native `Promise` methods